# How do I use HttpWebRequest with GET method

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, web-services, http

I have the following code which works just fine when the method is "POST", but changing to "GET" doesn't work:

```
HttpWebRequest request = null;
request = HttpWebRequest.Create(uri) as HttpWebRequest;
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8";
request.Method = "POST"; // Doesn't work with "GET"

request.BeginGetRequestStream(this.RequestCallback, null);
```

I get a `ProtocolViolationException` exception with the "GET" method.

**Edit:** After having a look using Reflector, it seems there is an explicit check for the "GET" method, if it's set to that it throws the exception.

**Edit2:** I've updated my code to the following, but it still throws an exception when I call EndGetResponse()

```
if (request.Method == "GET")
{
    request.BeginGetResponse(this.ResponseCallback, state);
}
else
{
    request.BeginGetRequestStream(this.RequestCallback, state);
}
```

In my function, ResponseCallback, I have this:

```
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(asyncResult);
```

Which throws the exception as well.

**Answer**

The above code now works, I had forgotten to take out the Content-Type line which was causing the exception to be thrown at the end. +1 to tweakt & answer to Jon.

The working code is now below:

```
HttpWebRequest request = null;
request = HttpWebRequest.Create(uri) as HttpWebRequest;
request.Method = "GET";// Supports POST too

if (request.Method == "GET")
{
    request.BeginGetResponse(this.ResponseCallback, state);
}
else
{
    request.BeginGetRequestStream(this.RequestCallback, state);
}
```

Comment: Still a ProtocolViolationException? Can you produce a short but complete program which demonstrates the problem? Have you looked on the wire (e.g. with Wireshark) to see what's happening?

Comment: Those two methods are completely different - `BeginGetResponse` is for making the web request, while `BeginGetRequestStream` is for writing the data to the stream..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is [specified in the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.begingetrequeststream.aspx). Basically GET requests aren't meant to contain bodies, so there's no sensible reason to call `BeginGetRequestStream`.

Comment: OK, that's fine - how do I use the HttpWebRequest with the GET method? I really don't want to have 2 logic paths dependent on whether it's GET/POST (using WebClient for GET).

Comment: Only fetch the request stream if you've got a body. If you've got a body and you're making a GET request, your bug is elsewhere.

Comment: There's no body, but I do need to get the request stream, as I'm getting the result from a REST api.

Comment: Sorry, meant the response stream - I need to get the result from the server.

Comment: No, that means you need the *response* stream. The request stream is the body you send. With GET, you don't send a body.

Comment: Darn I hate collisions. Yes, you need the response stream. If you try to do it synchronously, do you still get the error?

Comment: It's in Silverlight so I don't have that luxury :-/. (My choice of functions are BeginGetRequestStream / EndGetRequestStream & BeginGetResponse / EndGetResponse).

Answer (score 5):

Does it make sense for a GET request to send a Content-Type? Did you try removing the third line?

Comment: when dealing with phone7, in particular, this is a relevant answer. the act of setting contentType on a GET request will result in a protocol violation exception upon completion of the request.

Answer (score 1):

BeginGetRequestStream is used to get a stream specifically for writing data to the request. This is not applicable to GET requests.

The documentation for the BeginGetRequestStream method states explicitly that the method will throw a ProtocolViolationException if the Method is GET or HEAD.

Morale: read the docs ;-)

Answer (score 1):

It is specified in the documentation for the GetRequestStream that it will throw a ProtocolViolationException if the method is GET. However, I cannot find anything in the [HTTP spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html) to suggest that this is actually an HTTP protocol violation. Consider this a challenge.