# HttpWebRequest on Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, httpwebrequest

I have this code:

```
        private HttpWebRequest request;
        private HttpWebResponse wResponse;
        private CookieContainer cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        #region PRIVATE METHODS
        private void RunRequest(string url)
        {
            request = HttpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(url)) as HttpWebRequest;
            request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_7; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.16 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/10.0.648.205 Safari/534.16";
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            request.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;
            request.Method = "GET";

            StartWebRequest(request);

            //Do smthng
            while (wResponse == null) { }
        }

        private void StartWebRequest(HttpWebRequest request)
        {
            request.BeginGetResponse(FinishWebRequest, request);
        }

        private void FinishWebRequest(IAsyncResult result)
        {
            wResponse = (result.AsyncState as HttpWebRequest).EndGetResponse(result) as HttpWebResponse;
        }
        #endregion
```

And wRequest variable is not filled with any response. In AsyncState I have this:
[image: HttpWebRequest error]

What could be the problem?

p.s. The same code works good on the desktop-app.

Thanks, 
Pavel.

Comment: Duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/253549/how-do-i-use-httpwebrequest-with-get-method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/253549/how-do-i-use-httpwebrequest-with-get-method). The basic problem is that GET requests aren't supposed to have a body, which you are specifying with the ContentType. If you remove the ContentType line this should work.

Comment: I thought the same, but removing this line, I stopped getting IAsyncResult. Although the internet connection is good and I had to get an answer quickly.

Comment: I tried your code and it does work if you remove the `ContentType` and the `//do something` busy loop. Please post a complete example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems in your code.

1. You are not properly using asynchronous callback method:

   Replace

   `request.BeginGetResponse(FinishWebRequest, request);`

   with

   `request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(FinishWebRequest), request);`
2. Specifying Content-Type for GET request is invalid, it is essential
   for POST request. Modify `RunRequest()` method:

   ```
   private void RunRequest(string url, string method)
   {
       request = HttpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(url)) as HttpWebRequest;
       request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_7; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.16 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/10.0.648.205 Safari/534.16";
       request.Method = method; // method can be GET, POST etc.
       if (method == "POST")
           request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
       request.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;
       ...
   }
   ```

Comment: Your suggestion seems to be correct. But, unfortunately, working as you said, I can never get wResponse. It is always null. What else can I be doing wrong? :(

Comment: Do I need to set some permissions for applications that would grant access to the network?

Comment: Remove `while (wResponse == null) { }` from `RunRequest()` then place a breakpoint at the next line of `wResponse = (result.AsyncState as HttpWebRequest).EndGetResponse(result) as HttpWebResponse;` to see what it holds.

Comment: Nothing. This point does not reach. IAsyncResult is not returned by the BeginGetResponse method and do not passed to FinishWebRequest :(

Comment: Also, WebCLient class works well. But I need to use HttpWebRequest here.

Comment: Why do you need to add redundant delegate creation in `BeginGetResponse`? The compiler will generate the exact same code for `new AsyncCallback(FinishWebRequest)` and `FinishWebRequest`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to specify a ContentType when you are using a GET operation; removing that should solve the problem!

Comment: As I said before, after I removed this line, I stopped getting IAsyncResult. But the internet-connection is quite good.